# When does $(F,f): (X,A) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ induce isomorphisms on homology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider a map of topological pairs $(F,f): (X,A) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ consisting of a map $F: X \rightarrow Y$ and a map $f: A \rightarrow B$ such that $f$ is the restriction of $F$ from $A$ to $B$. We assume that $F$ and $f$ induce isomorphisms on all homology-modules. How can we show that also $(F,f)$ induces isomorphisms on all homology-modules? I guess one might be able to use functorial properties of the homology functor or some axioms like long exact sequence of a pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the long exact sequence induced on homology and the 5-lemma.

Comment: For what pairs?

Comment: For both. Both pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ have long exact sequences in homology. Write those as two rows, and connect then by vertical arrows which are the maps induced by $F,f$ and $(F,f).$ The diagram commutes by functoriality.